# RestKit issue with relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, restkit

I am using RestKit with Core Data and I am having trouble mapping the relationships between entities. The issue is that I have 3 different jsons (for 3 different screens) and these jsons have interrelated data. My 3 entities are Post, Conversation, and Message. The relationships are as such: Each post has many conversations (to-many relationship) and each conversation has many messages (to-many relationship).

Here is the first json for an array of posts:

```
{"success":true,"result":
[{"totalUsers":1,"lastMessageDate":1411612821000,"id":874,"title":"My post title"},
{"totalUsers":3,"lastMessageDate":1411536669000,"id":539,"title":"Message me"}]}
```

Here is the second json, which is an array of conversations for a specific post:

```
{"success":true,"result":
[{"badgeSize":1,"lastMessage":
{"id":1725,"text":"hey","datePublished":141153372347},"id":208,"username":"energydrink"}]}
```

Here is the third json for a particular conversation:

```
{"success":true,"result":
{"spamStatus":false,"messages":
[{"id":416,"text":"hello","datePublished":1403432789000},
{"id":380,"text":"whats up","datePublished":1403432144221}]}}
```

So as you can see, the data for the relationships is split up into 3 jsons. Here is how I have currently configured my relationships and response descriptor within RestKit:

```
[conversationMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"messages" toKeyPath:@"messages" withMapping:messageMapping]];

[postMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"conversations" toKeyPath:@"conversations" withMapping:messageMapping]];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:postMapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"result" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Since the response descriptor is mapped with postMapping, I am unable to correctly map data for the 2nd and 3rd jsons and then store within Core Data with my configuration. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Basically, I used RestKit's mapping for the first json. When `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` was called on the first view controller, I passed the post object to the second view controller. For the second json response, I deserialized the data and added the conversations to that post object. Then, I simply called `[[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error];`. Now it works just fine.